# Trying to replace the values of a column with values from another table column

Tags: mysql

This is what I got so far but it errors: MySQL

```
UPDATE item_template_epix 
   SET armor = 
       (SELECT armor 
         FROM item_template) 
 WHERE entry IN (SELECT entry FROM item_template WHERE armor > 1);
```

**Error:**

```
[Err] 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Comment: Like the error says, your subqueries are returning more than one row.  You either need to `top 1` each of them or add some other query restrictions to reduce them to a single row.

Comment: Search 'sql update with JOIN'.  As it is, you're telling it to update each value of your table with many other values, which doesn't work.

Comment: I am trying to do this for whole column,not only one row..

Comment: Each cell in that column needs to be given a single value.

Comment: Yes,that's the problem.I got 2 tables and I am trying to import column values from another

Comment: are you trying to assign a **single value** to that field/column for all returned rows?

Comment: Yes,that's what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
UPDATE item_template_epix 
JOIN item_template ON item_template_epix.entry = item_template.entry 
SET item_template_epix.armor = item_template.armor 
WHERE item_template.armor > 1
```

Comment: [Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM item_template_epix 
JOIN item_template ON item_template_epix.entry = item_' at line 3

Comment: Yeh... this is SQL server syntax, you should have specified that it was MySQL.

Comment: But it seems the mySQL syntax is pretty close, try my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
     UPDATE item_template_epix SET (armor) = (WITH OneValue AS 
     (SELECT entry FROM    item_template Where armor > 1))
                            SELECT armor FROM OneValue);
```

Comment: Unlucky but here's the error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(armor) = (WITH OneValue AS (SELECT armor 
     FROM item_template Where armor ' at line 1

Comment: Can you expand on how/why this works to answer the requestor's question?

Comment: "WITH OneValue AS "  is an Oracle property, I just noticed that you have Mysql platform. Sorry about the misunderstanding. This wont work for you then